# What is correct syntax to swap column values for selected rows in a pandas data frame using just one line?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) version 0.14.1 with Python 2.7.5, and I have a data frame with three columns, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'L':  ['left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right'],
     'R': ['right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left'],
     'VALUE': [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

idx = (df['VALUE'] == 1)
```

results in a data frame which looks like this:

```
       L      R  VALUE
0   left  right     -1
1  right   left      1
2   left  right     -1
3  right   left      1
4   left  right     -1
5  right   left      1
```

For rows where `VALUE == 1`, I would like to swap the contents of the left and right columns, so that all of the "left" values will end up under the "L" column, and the "right" values end up under the "R" column.

Having already defined the `idx` variable above, I can easily do this in just three more lines, by using a temporary variable as follows:

```
tmp = df.loc[idx,'L']
df.loc[idx,'L'] = df.loc[idx,'R']
df.loc[idx,'R'] = tmp
```

however this seems like really clunky and inelegant syntax to me; surely pandas supports something more succinct?  I've noticed that if I swap the column order in the input to the data frame `.loc` attribute, then I get the following swapped output:

```
In [2]: print(df.loc[idx,['R','L']])
      R      L
1  left  right
3  left  right
5  left  right
```

This suggests to me that I should be able to implement the same swap as above, by using just the following single line:

```
df.loc[idx,['L','R']] = df.loc[idx,['R','L']]
```

However when I actually try this, nothing happens--the columns remain unswapped.  It's as if pandas automatically recognizes that I've put the columns in the wrong order on the right hand side of the assignment statement, and it automatically corrects for the problem.  Is there a way that I can disable this "column order autocorrection" in pandas assignment statements, in order to implement the swap without creating unnecessary temporary variables?

Comment: Did you look at dataframe.eval? They have example in pandas docs: >>> df = DataFrame(randn(10, 2), columns=list('ab'))
>>> df.eval('a + b')
>>> df.eval('c = a + b')

Comment: For anyone who is curious, I've posted a followup question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811529/setting-values-on-a-subset-of-rows-indexing-boolean-setting

Comment: It needs to be noted that `idx = (df['VALUE'] == 1)` is not list of index! It is called a mask. Thus, can't be used in `df.iloc[...]`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One way you could avoid alignment on column names would be to drop down to the underlying array via `.values`:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]: 
       L      R  VALUE
0   left  right     -1
1  right   left      1
2   left  right     -1
3  right   left      1
4   left  right     -1
5  right   left      1

In [34]: df.loc[idx,['L','R']] = df.loc[idx,['R','L']].values

In [35]: df
Out[35]: 
      L      R  VALUE
0  left  right     -1
1  left  right      1
2  left  right     -1
3  left  right      1
4  left  right     -1
5  left  right      1
```

Comment: This seems to only work properly if the Series _idx_ has dtype _bool_. If your series is values 0/1 instead of True/False, convert to dtype _bool_ using `idx.astype(bool)`.

Comment: It needs to be noted that using `df.loc`, you are operating in `DataFrame` indexing, while in the `idx` and `.values`, you are operating in `NumPy` indexing. If you have different value of indexing, it can cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 11):

The key thing to note here is that pandas attempts to automatically align rows and columns using the index and column names.  Hence, you need to somehow tell pandas to ignore the column names here.  One way is as @DSM does, by converting to a numpy array.  Another way is to rename the columns:

```
>>> df.loc[idx] = df.loc[idx].rename(columns={'R':'L','L':'R'})

      L      R  VALUE
0  left  right     -1
1  left  right      1
2  left  right     -1
3  left  right      1
4  left  right     -1
5  left  right      1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response; I gave "accepted answer" status to DSM since he answered first, but I found your answer also quite helpful (and therefore upvoted it!) as well.  BTW, I think there may be a typo in your first method; on my system, with pandas 0.14.1 and Python 2.7.5, it works if I instead add a call to `zip`; i.e., `df.ix[idx,['L','R']] = zip(df.ix[idx,'R'], df.ix[idx,'L'])`.  The second method works just fine, so thanks for that!  For the 3rd method, I think the problem is that the `df[['R','L']] on the right side is 6 rows long, while the `df.loc[idx,['L','R']]` is only 3 rows.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Method 1 works fine for me without the zip (and also if I add the zip).  No idea why we get different results.  I've got pandas 14.1 and python 2.7.7 (anaconda distribution).  Running under windows 7.

Comment: `df.update(df.loc[m].rename({'L': 'R', 'R': 'L'}, axis=1))` works just as well.

Comment: If we use numpy mask `idx = df['VALUE'].values == 1` instead of DataFrame mask `idx = df['VALUE'] == 1` , this will not working.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this with `np.select` and `df.where` i.e

**Option 1**: `np.select`

```
df[['L','R']] = pd.np.select(df['VALUE'] == 1, df[['R','L']].values, df[['L','R']].values)
```

**Option 2**: `df.where`

```
df[['L','R']] = df[['R','L']].where(df['VALUE'] == 1, df[['L','R']].values)
```

**Option 3**: `df.mask`

```
df[['L','R']] = df[['L','R']].mask( df['VALUE'] == 1, df[['R','L']].values)
```

Output:

```
    L      R  VALUE
0  left  right     -1
1  left  right      1
2  left  right     -1
3  left  right      1
4  left  right     -1
5  left  right      1
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, `df.update(df.loc[m].rename({'L': 'R', 'R': 'L'}, axis=1))` is the best.

As mentioned by @cs95 in the comment of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25793732/11671779), `df.update(df.loc[m].rename({'L': 'R', 'R': 'L'}, axis=1))` will works.

Why it is better?

Because it support both NumPy and DataFrame mask.

```py
d = {'L':  ['left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right'],
     'R': ['right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left'],
     'VALUE': [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df_mask = df['VALUE'] == 1
df.update(df.loc[df_mask].rename({'L': 'R', 'R': 'L'}, axis=1))
df
```

```py
d = {'L':  ['left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right'],
     'R': ['right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left'],
     'VALUE': [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

np_mask = df['VALUE'].values == 1
df.update(df.loc[np_mask].rename({'L': 'R', 'R': 'L'}, axis=1))
df
```

Thus, if used as function, user can give a flexible indexing method.

Furthermore, to be safe, if NumPy indexing is used, it also support `iloc` instead of `loc`. Sadly, `iloc` does not support DataFrame indexing as for version '1.3.5'.

```py
d = {'L':  ['left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right'],
     'R': ['right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left'],
     'VALUE': [-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

np_mask = df['VALUE'].values == 1
df.update(df.iloc[np_mask].rename({'L': 'R', 'R': 'L'}, axis=1))
df
```