# Setting values on a subset of rows (indexing, boolean setting)

Tags: python, pandas

This is a followup to:

[What is correct syntax to swap column values for selected rows in a pandas data frame using just one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792619/what-is-correct-syntax-to-swap-column-values-for-selected-rows-in-a-pandas-data/25793732#25793732)

No credit will be given for a workaround, only for an explanation.  There are already three workarounds provided as answers to the original question.

There are 3 examples of setting values below.  How can you explain different results?  Why do #1 and #2 fail in different ways while #3 works fine? Is this behavior buggy or actually the way things should work?

```
df = DataFrame({'L':   ['left', 'right', 'left', 'right'],
                'R':   ['right', 'left', 'right', 'left'],
                'idx': [False, True, False, True],
                'num': np.arange(4) })

df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()
df3 = df.copy()

#1 nothing happens
df1.loc[df1.idx,['L','R']] = df1.loc[df1.idx,['R','L']]

#2 weird results
df2.loc[df2.idx,['L','R']] = df2[['R','L']]

#3 similar to #2, works fine
df3.loc[df3.idx,['L','R']] = df3['num']
```

data before and after:

```
df
       L      R    idx  num
0   left  right  False    0
1  right   left   True    1
2   left  right  False    2
3  right   left   True    3

df1
       L      R    idx  num
0   left  right  False    0
1  right   left   True    1
2   left  right  False    2
3  right   left   True    3

df2
       L      R    idx  num
0   left  right  False    0
1   left  right   True    1
2   left  right  False    2
3  right   left   True    3

df3
       L      R    idx  num
0   left  right  False    0
1      1      1   True    1
2   left  right  False    2
3      3      3   True    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas *aligns* the right-hand side of a setting operation. Then take the left-hand side mask and sets them equal.

So this is the left hand indexer. So you are going to be making the rhs this same shape (or broadcastable to it).

```
In [61]: df1.loc[df1.idx,['L','R']] 
Out[61]: 
       L     R
1  right  left
3  right  left
```

Here is the first. I am only going to show the right-hand alignment (the y).

```
In [49]: x, y = df1.align(df1.loc[df1.idx,['L','R']])

In [51]: y
Out[51]: 
       L     R  idx  num
0    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
1  right  left  NaN  NaN
2    NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN
3  right  left  NaN  NaN
```

So even though you reversed the columns in the input on the right hand side, aligning put them back in order. So you are setting the same values, hence no change.

```
In [63]: x, y = df2.align(df2[['R','L']])

In [65]: y
Out[65]: 
       L      R  idx  num
0   left  right  NaN  NaN
1  right   left  NaN  NaN
2   left  right  NaN  NaN
3  right   left  NaN  NaN
```

Notice the difference from the above. This is still a full frame (and not sub-selected, so the *shape* of the right hand side is now != to the left shape, as opposed to the above example).

Their is a reindexing step at this point. It *might* be a bug as I think this should come out the same as the your first example. Pls file a bug report for this (e.g. your example using df1 and df2). They should come out == df after the assignment.

```
In [58]: x, y = df1.align(df3['num'],axis=0)

In [60]: y
Out[60]: 
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
Name: num, dtype: int64
```

This one simply broadcasts the results to the left-hand side. that's why the numbers are propogated.

Bottom line. Pandas attempts to figure out the right hand side in the assignment. Their are a lot of cases.

Comment: Thanks Jeff!  So align is the special sauce...  That is very helpful to know for visualizing what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: thanks. This is fairly hairy code, so certainly possible that is not 100% consistent.