# pandas - how to combine selected rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I've been reading a huge (5 GB) gzip file in the form:

```
   User1  User2  W
0     11     12  1
1     12     11  2
2     13     14  1
3     14     13  2
```

which is basically a directed graph representation of connections among users with a certain weight W. Since the file is so big, I tried to read it through networkx, building a Directed Graph and then set it to Undirected. But it took too much time. So I was thinking in doing the same thing analysing a pandas dataframe. I would like to return the previous dataframe in the form:

```
   User1  User2  W
0     11     12  3
1     13     14  3
```

where the common links in the two directions have been merged into one having as W the sum of the single weights. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a more concise way, but this works.  The main trick is just to normalize the data such that User1 is always the lower number ID.  Then you can use `groupby` since `11,12` and `12,11` are now recognized as representing the same thing.

```
In [330]: df = pd.DataFrame({"User1":[11,12,13,14],"User2":[12,11,14,13],"W":[1,2,1,2]})

In [331]: df['U1'] = df[['User1','User2']].min(axis=1)
In [332]: df['U2'] = df[['User1','User2']].max(axis=1)

In [333]: df = df.drop(['User1','User2'],axis=1)

In [334]: df.groupby(['U1','U2'])['W'].sum()
Out[334]: 
U1  U2
11  12    3
13  14    3
Name: W, dtype: int64
```

For more concise code that avoids creating new variables, you could replace the middle 3 steps with:

```
In [400]: df.ix[df.User1>df.User2,['User1','User2']] = df.ix[df.User1>df.User2,['User2','User1']].values
```

Note that column switching can be trickier than you'd think, see here:  [What is correct syntax to swap column values for selected rows in a pandas data frame using just one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792619/what-is-correct-syntax-to-swap-column-values-for-selected-rows-in-a-pandas-data/25793732#25793732)

As far as making this code fast in general, it will depend on your data.  I don't think the above code will be as important as other things you might do.  For example, your problem should be amenable to a chunking approach where you iterate over sections of the code, gradually shrinking it on each pass.  In that case, the main thing you need to think about is sorting the data before chunking, so as to minimize how many passes you need to make.  But doing it that way should allow you to do all the work in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the trick! It works, but since I'm working with big big files, I'm looking also for something more concise. I'm thinking about that, but thanks again!

Comment: OK.  Actually conciseness and speed are not necessarily related here (or in general!), but I'll show a more concise method and I'll add a couple of comments about speed considerations.

Comment: OK, too late!  I'll just leave the comments in at this point.  Glad that worked for you.