# Swap values in the columns and rows under specific conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a following pandas dataframe:

[image]

and I want to check if the value in the column `'A start'` is negative. If negative than swap values in column `'start'` and `'end'` and in columns `'A start'` and `'A end'` in the row where the

`'A start'` has a negative value. So the result should be:

[image]

I tried to solve it with `where` but it doesn't worked.

I'm using python 3.8.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest method using `where`

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['start']   = [1,5,7,2]
df['end']     = [4,6,8,9,]
df['A start'] = [234, -475, -765, 113]
df['A end']   = [-654, 312, 987, -553]


df[['A start','A end']] = df[['A end','A start']].where(df['A start'] < 0 , df[['A start','A end']].values)
df
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Great . Make sure to approve the answer !

Answer (score 0):

Hey look at this post it is similar to your question it might help! If not let me know can look for other options.

[What is correct syntax to swap column values for selected rows in a pandas data frame using just one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792619/what-is-correct-syntax-to-swap-column-values-for-selected-rows-in-a-pandas-data)

Comment: Unfortunately the link you sent doesn't help