# Sorting values between column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

Assume I have this simple dataframe

```
matrix = [(222, 16, 23),
          (333, 31, 51),
          (4, 34, 11),
          ]
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, index=list('abc'), columns=list('xyz'))
```

[image]

I want to order by the value ignoring the columns like this

[image]

Right now I am using the swapping idea in pandas from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792619/what-is-correct-syntax-to-swap-column-values-for-selected-rows-in-a-pandas-data) and doing brute force sort

```
df.loc[df['x']>df['y'],['x','y']] = df.loc[df['x']>df['y'],['y','x']].values
df.loc[df['x']>df['z'],['x','z']] = df.loc[df['x']>df['z'],['z','x']].values
df.loc[df['y']>df['z'],['y','z']] = df.loc[df['y']>df['z'],['z','y']].values
```

It is working but actually I have more columns than 3, and I will be grateful if someone can give me another idea to sort this data, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a strange request - usually the columns contain semantic meaning.  You can do it via:

```
cols = df.columns
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=1), columns=cols, index=df.index)
```

output:

```
    x   y    z
a  16  23  222
b  31  51  333
c  4  11    34
```

Comment: Thank you @anon01 for the idea. I never think of transposing the dataframe, it should solve this question
but actually my data is more complex and each data has pairs in another column so if I swap "16" (a,x) there is another values that need to be swapped too because it is a pair. But I think I can try to use this idea

Comment: but, why do you want to interchange data with labels?  That's highly unusual

Comment: This doesn't match the expected output row `c 4 11 34` but your output has `c 34 11 4`.

Comment: so the column is actually similar things like, product1, product2, product3 that can be interchanged, and somehow I need to sort that

Comment: it is int, sorry for my bad analogy but something like that
maybe product_id1, product_id2, product_id3, price_1, price_2, price_3

Comment: @anon01 Because they are sort like tuples

Comment: We can use `np.sort` here tho.

Comment: @anon01 Think of them as tuples. In pandas sorting it reorders the either whole column or rows. `df.sort_values(list("abc"), axis=1)` here whole column is compared with another column rather than each values. Since column `y`'s first value is 16 it came to 0th index in column, next column `z` has 23 so it came to 1st index likewise for other columns. Here whole column moves not single values in them.

Comment: In much simpler terms what did is equivalent to `sorted(zip(*matrix))` -> `[(16, 31, 34), (23, 51, 11), (222, 333, 4)]`

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=1), columns=cols, index=df.index)` you missed `index=df.index` else index would be `RangeIndex` i.e. `0 1 2`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.sort` over axis 1 here:

```
# df
#      x   y   z
# a  222  16  23
# b  333  31  51
# c    4  34  11

df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=1),
                  columns=df.columns,
                  index=df.index)

    x   y    z
a  16  23  222
b  31  51  333
c   4  11   34
```