# Sorting one group of columns according to another group of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, sorting

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65435123/sorting-values-between-column-using-pandas/65435322#65435170), the last time I thought it will be that simple but it seems not (thank you @anon01 and @Ch3steR who answered my previous question there)

so here is my new dataframe

```
matrix = [(1, 3, 2, "1a", "3a", "2a"),
          (6, 5, 4, "6a", "5a", "4a"),
          (8, 7, 9, "8a", "7a", "9a"),
          ]
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, index=list('abc'), columns=["price1","price2","price3","product1","product2","product3"])

    price1  price2  price3  product1    product2    product3
a   1         3       2       1a           3a         2a
b   6         5       4       6a           5a         4a
c   8         7       9       8a           7a         9a
```

I need to sort by price within each row but price and product is a pairs so if the price move to price1 then the product also need to move to product1 because they are pairs
Here is the output will be

```
        price1  price2  price3  product1    product2    product3
a         1       2        3       1a         2a          3a
b         4       5        6       4a         5a          6a
c         7       8        9       7a         8a          9a
```

from the last question, I tried the suggested solution using np.sort it can work to sort the price but if I have another column it is not working. I tried to rematching the product with the price but I think it will cost more so I still using my previous brute force solution as using swapping from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792619/what-is-correct-syntax-to-swap-column-values-for-selected-rows-in-a-pandas-data)

```
df.loc[df['price1']>df['price2'],['price1','price2','product1','product2']] = df.loc[df['price1']>df['price2'],['price2','price1','product2','product1']].values
df.loc[df['price1']>df['price3'],['price1','price3','product1','product3']] = df.loc[df['price1']>df['price3'],['price3','price1','product3','product1']].values
df.loc[df['price2']>df['price3'],['price2','price3','product2','product3']] = df.loc[df['price2']>df['price3'],['price3','price2','product3','product2']].values
```

The problem is I have more pairs than 3
if someone has an idea for this matter, it will be very helpful, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can make use of [`numpy.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) for "price", and [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy.argsort) for product. This is all vectorized by numpy.

```
# Gets all "price" columns
price = df.filter(like='price')
# Gets all "product" columns
product = df.filter(like='product')

# Sorts "price" columns row-wise and assigns an array back
df[price.columns] = np.sort(price.to_numpy(), axis=1)

# Builds indices for re-organizing "product" based on sorted "price" 
ix = np.arange(product.shape[1])[:,None]
iy = np.argsort(price.to_numpy(), axis=1)
# Re-arranges "product" array and assigns it back  
df[product.columns] = product.to_numpy()[ix, iy]
```

```
df
   price1  price2  price3 product1 product2 product3
a       1       2       3       1a       2a       3a
b       4       5       6       4a       5a       6a
c       7       8       9       7a       8a       9a
```

Comment: Comments inlined.

Comment: thank you it is works, I think I can use more columns with this

Comment: @d_frEak Potentially as many as you want, as long as `len(price.columns) == len(product.columns)` is True. (You could potentially add an if check to guard against erroneous cases in the code if you want.)

Comment: yeah. I also planning using loop for product, because actually the pairs is not only (price, product) but more, so I plan to using price to sort columns row-wise and re-organizing the rest of the column
thank you

Comment: @cs95 great answer. wish you a very happy Christmas :-)