# Python - np.Where condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with pandas and I have this table (prod)

| id | quantity | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | pack |
| 2 | pack | 3 |
| 3 | 6 | pack |
| 4 | pack | 6 |
| 5 | 6 | 9 |

I'm want to do a when condition to help me sort out wrong inserted information

| id | quantity | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | pack |
| **2** | **3** | **pack** |
| 3 | 6 | pack |
| **4** | **6** | **pack** |
| 5 | 6 | 9 |

I would simply use ISNUMERIC() on SQL Server, how can I achieve this on Python?

I have tried

> np.where(np.isnumeric(type),prod['quantity'],prod['type'))

any feedback on what I'm doing wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
prod = pd.DataFrame({'quantity': [18, 'pack', 6, 'pack', 6], 'type': ['pack', 3, 'pack', 6, 9]}, index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
prod.index.name = 'id'

cond = prod.type.astype(str).str.isnumeric() & ~prod.quantity.astype(str).str.isnumeric()
# or 
# cond = prod.quantity.map(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))  # to swap if some values in the 'quantity' column is str
prod.loc[cond, ['type', 'quantity']] = prod.loc[cond, ['quantity', 'type']].values # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/25792812/15035314
print(prod)
```

Output:

```
   quantity  type
id               
1        18  pack
2         3  pack
3         6  pack
4         6  pack
5         6     9
```

Comment: first option wont return me anything and second keeps telling me '' 'float' object has no attribute 'isnumeric''' :(

Comment: Edited, see the last version