# Shifting rows based on current column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, shift

I'm trying to shift all rows that have an E in colB to be blank in colA and then the values of colA and colB shifted over 1.

Everything I search on shift or adjusting has to do with moving columns up or down. I haven't found this solution yet.

Edit: I gave a poor example here. There needs to be 2 unchanged columns in the front of colA. That was the shifting I was having and issue with. Not a standard shift. Again my apologies for the bad example.

```
df =
   col0 col1 colA colB colC
0    Z    A   1    2    A
1    Z    A   3    E    
2    Z    A   8    7    B
3    Z    A   3    E    
4    Z    A   7    C

# Desired Output:

df_shifted =
   col0 col1 colA colB colC
0    Z    A   1    2    A
1    Z    A        3    E    
2    Z    A   8    7    B
3    Z    A        3    E    
4    Z    A   7    C
```

I've tried using Shift commands or even splitting my base data differently. I can't seem to find a better solution than what I'm looking for here.

This is what I tried but to no avail

```
df  = pd.DataFrame(
    {
'colZ' :["z", "z", "z", "z", "z"],
'colX' :["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
'colA' :(1,3,8,3,7),
'colB' :(2, "E", 7, "E", "C"),
'colC' :("A", "", "B", "", "")
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame()

df2["colZ"] = df["colZ"]
df2["colX"] = df["colX"]



df[df['colB'] == 'E'] = df[df['colB'] == 'E'].shift(1, axis=1).fillna('')

df_shifted = pd.DataFrame()

df_shifted["colZ"] = df2["colZ"]
df_shifted["colX"] = df2["colX"]
df_shifted["colA"] = df["colA"]
df_shifted["colB"] = df["colB"]
df_shifted["colC"] = df["colC"]

# Result from this code

df_shifted = 
  colZ colX colA colB colC
0    z    A    1    2    A
1    z    A    A    3    E
2    z    A    8    7    B
3    z    A    A    3    E
4    z    A    7    C
```

Also this seems super long for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, sorry. I gave a really poor example of my actual problem. Still learning Pandas. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) operation along the column axis and subsequent filling of NaNs is still (after editing the original question) the most efficient method

```py
df.loc[df['colB'] == 'E', ['colA', 'colB', 'colC']] = df.loc[df['colB']=='E', ['colA', 'colB', 'colC']].shift(1, axis=1).fillna('')
```

which yields

```
>df
  col0 col1 colA colB colC
 0    Z    A    1    2    A
 1    Z    A         3    E
 2    Z    A    8    7    B
 3    Z    A         3    E
 4    Z    A    7    C
```

Comment: I gave a real crap example thank you for answer so quickly. This does solve what I originally posted but the problem is more complex. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh thanks man. I see how how the syntax holds it there. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48039682/9167382) answer, you can use `where`:

```
df[['colA','colB','colC']] = df[['colC','colA','colB']].where(df['colB'] == "E", df[['colA','colB','colC']].values)
```

prints:

```
  colA colB colC
0    1    2    A
1  NaN    3    E
2    8    7    B
3  NaN    3    E
4    6    7    C
```

Comment: I gave a really bad example thank you for your input see my update. The standard shift I've got down I just cant seem to keep the front 2 columns stationary.